# Matlab, DFT, FFT, frequency range;

Tags: matlab, fft, dft

I am really having a hard time to understand how the fft-function in MATLAB works.
According to:

http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/math/fast-fourier-transform-fft.html

fs/n is the distance between the sampled points in the Spectrum, where fs is the sampling frequency and n is the length of the signal. The code that they present, does extract the frequencies (although I do not know why), but according to the implementation of fft, that they present:

http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

the distance between the points in the spectrum should rather be: 1/fs. Because instead of the index j one inserts j*T, where T = 1/fs is the sampling time and then you can calculate the distance between the points, which should not be fs/n.

I would really be grateful if someone could explain me what the distance between the points in the frequency domain is and why this is so:)

[EDIT]
This is not a Matlab-specific problem. It is more a problem about the relationship between the Fourier-Transformation and the Discrete-Fourier-Transformation and the scaling/units of the frequency-axis. A pretty good explanation can be found in this [PDF-Document](http://texas.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/ttu/dft.pdf) at page 3.

[/EDIT]

Comment: Are you talking about where `f = (0:n-1)*(fs/n)` and `t = (0:L-1)*T;`? Do you realise that there are time and frequency - two different things? I am getting the feeling that you are getting confused with how the plots have been done using f, Fs, and T.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about f = (0:(n-1))*(fs/n); i.e the frequency range. The Time range is correct, but the frequency range does not make sense to me. If you have a look at the formula for the DFT, which MATLAB used for the implementation, you see in the exponent:

Comment: (−2πi)/N*(j-1)*(k-1) where j is the index of the sum and the time index in x(j), and k is the index of the Spectrum. Since x was sampled at x(jT), one should use this for the frequency range (in Hertz, if T is in seconds): `f = (0:n-1)*(1/fs);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance between the frequency points on the spectrum is `fs/n` in both cases, and that is the correct value. If we take the code in http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fft.html, we have:

```
>> Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
>> T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
>> L = 1000;                     % Length of signal
>> t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
>> NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
>> f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
>> f(2)-f(1)
ans =  0.97656
>> Fs/NFFT
ans =  0.97656
```

You can double-check all the other `f(n+1)-f(n)`, they're all the same.

Comment: I am talking about the frequence range in units: 1/second. Please see my comment above (especially the part about the DFT)

Comment: Even dimensionally, it doesn't make sense: `1/fs` is the same dimension as time [s], so how can it be a frequency unit (which is 1/s)?

Comment: But you need to put this value in the exponent of the e-function in the formula of the DFT, then the index k is equivalent to Hertz.

Comment: No, you don't. `k` is just an index, without any dimension associated. The correct frequency spacing is `fs/n`.

Comment: If you have a look at the theoretical background of the Fouriertransformation the exponent looks like this: -2πi*(j-1)*Ts*f. Now f is sampled at f = (k-1)/N, k in [1..N], where N is the length of the signal (x(j))so you get for the exponent: -2πi*(j-1)*(k-1)*Ts/N. If you compare this exponent with Matlabs implementation of the DFT/FFT in [link](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), you will find that you have to multiply k with Ts in order for both exponent to be equal. So the vector for the frequency range in 1/s should look like this: `f = (0:n-1)*(1/fs);` or `f = (0:n-1)*Ts;`

Comment: No, `f` is not sampled at `f = (k-1)/N`, `f` is sampled at `f = fs*(k-1)/N`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, the frequency is sampled at: f_k = k/(N*Fs). However the relationship between the Fouriertransformation and the DFT is more complicated. One can use following equation to approximate the Fouriertransformation of a signal with the DFT: F(k/(N*Ts)) ≈ Ts * F_k, where F_k is the DFT according to the formula in: [link](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/fft.html). Here I found a pretty good explanation for this: [link](http://bit.ly/1t0PrY9)