# How do I calculate the DFT with dt=0.02?

Tags: matlab, dft

Now I'm trying to understand how does DFT work.
So I've implemented with matlab this to do as the below matlab code.

the function is

[image]

and

[image]

```
clear all
clc

N=8;
dt=0.02;
fs=1/dt;
T=0.16;
tspan = (0:N-1)/fs;
y = 5+cos(2*pi*12.5*tspan)+sin(2*pi*18.75*tspan);


X=zeros(1,N);

for k = 0:N-1
    for n = 0:N-1
        X(k+1) = X(k+1) + y(n+1)*exp(-j*(2*pi/N)*k*n);
    end
end

x_mag = abs(X);
plot(0:N-1,x_mag);
```

I was expecting the result as this

[image]

but I've got

[image]

What am I supposed to do get correct result?

update

If I've added N to 80 from 8, then I've got the below graph but
this result also seemed to be wrong.

[image]

frequency is appeared as 20 and 30 not 12.5 and 18.75.

Update #1

I found something rules with the below the Matlab code. When I run with N=350 then
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feZXV.jpg)

```
   dt=0.02 
    fs=1/dt % hz = 1/0.02 (delta T)

     N=350;

     tspan = (0:N-1)*dt; 
     y = 5+cos(2*pi*12.5*tspan)+sin(2*pi*18.75*tspan);

    X=y;

    X=zeros(1,N);

    for k = 0:N-1
        for n = 0:N-1
            X(k+1) = X(k+1) + y(n+1)*exp(-j*(2*pi/N)*k*n);
        end
    end

    x_mag = abs(X);
    plot(0:N-1,x_mag);
```

and when I have N=50 then I can the below graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZPqp.jpg)

I think When I have N=50, it seems to be more correct result.

But I can't understand How do we decide the proper N?

Comment: If you have 8 samples you don't have enough information to properly describe 12.5 Hz and 18.75 Hz content.  You need more points.  Also your DC bias (0 Hz content) is not removed.  Subtract the mean to remove that content.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for letting me know that, But I didn't get it exactly. Would you mind let me know how many point what I needed ? and how can I remove the DC bias?

Comment: @start01 Related to that question https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/fourier-transform-minimum-sample-requirement Also check out [Nyquist Sampling Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)

Comment: @jodag Thanks I think you want to say that I have to have the sample number the same as Nyquist number.

Comment: @start01 yes. More is good too, but not less.

Comment: You are not plotting against frequency but against index, see the answer here: [fft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591378/matlab-dft-fft-frequency-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the exact result that you should get. Read the description of the function [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/discrete-fourier-transform.html).

So wats happening ist you are sampling 80 points in time, that means you get 80 poins in frequency space. Since your function is real, not complex, the DFT is symmetric and arraged around the midpoint of 80 samples, meaning around 40.

*(And you are also plotting in index-space, not frequency space!)*

From 40 you have the symmetric Fourier transform with positive and negaive frequencies the same (real function in time space). If you count from 40, you probably get the peaks at exactly 12.5 (52.5) and 18.75 (58.75) Hz as you wanted to.

Hope this helps.

Some code from the [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html):

```
Y = fft(X);
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);

f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
plot(f,P1) 
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of X(t)')
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')
```

Comment: Thanks but now I'm trying to implement without MATLAB function of FFT.

Comment: It should work the same with your user function. Its basically the same function, you get the same result. Just take half of the length, since you and reindex your results so it maps frequencies.

Comment: Thanks I think  I've seen it before from MATLAB site. But I can't understand How do we decide the proper N in my case? and How does it explain in case of N=50 and N=350? they have different results.

Comment: they don't have different results. The resolution is better for higher N, and it should work as long as you don't go below he Nyquist limit. 
You get the frequencies by rescaling with the respective formula (I think it's df = Fs/N, with Fssampling frequency)